# How to view all mallocs in valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

Normally to run valgrind to check for memory leaks I'll do something like this:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./main

==1431== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1431== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1431==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1431==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==1431==
==1431== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1431==
==1431== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1431== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is there a way where I can see where the following `malloc` / `free` was done, even though it doesn't result in an error?

```
==1431==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
```

The program I am running is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hi\n");
}
```

The `malloc` is located in the `printf` (obviously) and when I comment out that line the `mallocs` go away in valgrind: but how can I see the 'trace' for the malloc within the `printf` function?

Here is what shows from using `massif`:

```
n1: 1024 (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
 n1: 1024 0x4EB11FA: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
  n1: 1024 0x4EC13E7: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:365)
   n1: 1024 0x4EC0506: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:759)
    n1: 1024 0x4EBEA5B: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1266)
     n1: 1024 0x4EB3AFD: puts (ioputs.c:40)
      n0: 1024 0x108648: main (main.c:4)
```

But it's a bit opaque to me how the `printf` goes that far into the function calls to do the allocations.

Comment: Could be an internal allocation of stdlib.

Comment: Maybe that's just the output buffer for `printf` versus `stdout`?

Comment: @tadman what do you mean by `stdout` vs `printf` ? How it does line-buffering by default for printf?

Comment: @tadman by the way, how can I jump into the code for something like `puts (ioputs.c:40)`? Is that the line of the header-file and I have to look up online glibc, or what's the best way to dig into that?